# How to use different CSV for each thread using jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am new to jmeter. My scenario is like there are multiple  users who wants to login and perform a search based on id's specific to the user.

**For eg,**

> user1 will have 100 id's and placed it in user1.csv
>   user2 will have another 100 id's and placed it in user2.csv

Each user have to perform a search for each id available in the csv file.

So I have placed my request in loop controller and it works fine for single user. But if i run for 2 users, both thread refers to the user1.csv. How to make user2 to refer user2.csv.

Kindly suggest me how to achieve this in jmeter? Or is there any other different approach to do it? Please provide detailed explanation since am new to jmeter. I want to chk this for 100 users.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want 100 users (threads) to each use a different set of variables a very simple solution would be to have a single CSV file with 5 IDs per line and 100 lines like this:

```
ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4, ID5
  1,   9,   2,   5, 20
 33, 212,   7,   8, 22
```

... etc

Here's a blog on how to use the JMeter CSV data set config:
http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config

Comment: I tried this and it works for 5 id's. But its really pain if i want to use more than 500 id's. I think its not better to use 500 variables in csv data set. Is there any possible approch to use more than 500 id's for each users?

Comment: CSV data set config doesn't support dynamic filenames. You can skip entering the variables names in JMeter by adding the column names in the CSV: Variable Names List of variable names (comma-delimited). Versions of JMeter after 2.3.4 support CSV header lines: if the variable name field empty, then the first line of the file is read and interpreted as the list of column names. The names must be separated by the delimiter character. They can be quoted using double-quotes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. Instead of using csv data set config, is their any other possiblity? Because providing 500 ids in csv file is little complex if the no. of thread is more than 100. If there is any other possible approac, kindly explain me with an example