# how to use separate csv file for each thread

Tags: jmeter

My scenario is like,
1. Login by multiple users (100 users)
2. Select 50 items by id's specific to user

I have placed id's for each user in separate csv file say user1.csv, user2.csv, user3.csv and so on.

My result should be like Thread 1 should take user1.csv and process all 50 id's in loop controller.
Thread 2 should take user2.csv and so on.

I tried with below example, but still couldn't find the solution.

Eg. I used file path as C:\abc\user${_threadNum}.csv

Or

C:\abc\user${_threadNum}.csv

Variable name in csv file is user_id

Requeat will look like /home/abc/${user_id}

I want thread 1 to use the user1.csv file and substitiue the value of user_id in the request and thread 2 should use user2.csv and so on.

If I execute my above plan, I am getting error as /home/abc/EOF

How is this possible in JMeter? Or any other approach?

Please provide solution with an example, since I am new to JMeter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use different CSV for each thread using jmeter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21291668/how-to-use-different-csv-for-each-thread-using-jmeter)

Comment: I am also getting the same EOF as data from CSV for all columns. How to step further ? can anybody please help.

Answer (score 2):

Create your files like comman_name_1,comman_name_2,comman_name_3
 etc. & select current thread option from dropdown list present in csv data config set.This will allow threads to use different files per thread or put values in a single file and select   current thread option.

Comment: Hi, as your suggestion i have created my csv files. In the csv data config set, i also selected current thread option. But what should be the file name? If am having 5 csv files, do i need to create 5 separate csv data set config with same variable name? If single csv data set is enough, then what should be the filename? How each thread will take separate csv file?

Comment: I'll write stepwise,
1. create 5 files like file1,file2,file3 etc.
2. create 2 csv data configs in your script 1 for actual users who will login in your case and 2 for those 50 ids which you will test 
3. in first data config file (input file)user names will be present
4. in second data config write file name as file${counter} (check syntax) and set mode as current thread (this will access file1 for first user ,file2 for 2nd user and so on )
5. for using $counter you will have to use counter in your test plan   starting from 1-5 
I hope you will get this :)

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation.. I wil try this out.. Also i need some clarification.. Instead of ${counter}, i tried using ${_threadNum} (check my question). But i am getting EOF error. Is it possible to use ${_threadNum} instead of counter? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hi, i tried with your option. But am getting as EOF error instead of filename. Can you suggest what could be solution?

Comment: I am also getting the same EOF as data from CSV for all columns. How to step further ? can anybody please help.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, just add [CSV Data Set Config](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config) to each thread (user1.csv for thread1 and so forth). Configure CSV Data Set config, and select one of this values in Sharing mode field:

- Current thread group - each file is opened once for each thread group
  in which the element appears
- Current thread - each file is opened separately for each thread

UPD: I have done it right now, it works

Script looks like this:

[image: CSVExample]

I selected 'Current thread' in each CSV Data Set Config

Comment: Hi jay, i tried with your option but still all thread refering to user1.csv. Can u explain me with an example?

Comment: you have used different thread group. But i want everything in same thread group. Please see my updated question

Comment: As per your script, if i want to execute for 100 users, i need to create 100 thread group? Please let me know if your not clear with my question. If so I wil try to explain in detail. Thanks in advance jay

Comment: Oh, now I understood... And one of decisions is to separate you script into some thread groups. If you want 100 users, you could configure it in each Thread group, in the 'Number of Threads (users)' field.

Comment: 100 users should use different csv. If i provide number of thread as 100, all thread refering to the same csv i.e duck.csv... My logic is simple, there are 100 csv file and 100 user (theard) should use only 1 csv file as i mentioned in my question. Next, there will be unique 50 id's inside each csv file. Request should process each id's separately in loop controller.

Answer (score 0):

I was making the mistake of using single underscore in fetching the count of thread.
We need to use double - underscore like this :   ${__threadNum}
 Note :