# jMeter: use separated .csv file for each each thread

Tags: jmeter

I want to run 5 threads and each thread pulls in data from different .csv file. For example, thread 1 maps to data_1.csv... I do NOT want to create 5 Thread Groups.

Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to open different csv files in the same test plan execution, you have to build a file name with the [threadNum function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum).

According to your example you would have to set the filename to "**data_${__threadNum}.csv**" in the csv reader so the 5 threads will load your 5 files.

The files are shared upon their filenames so the sharing mode is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to [usermanual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) `By default, the file is only opened once, and each thread will use a different line from the file.` You can change sharing mode but not open several different CSV files, i.e. one file for each thread.

Upd: on the other hand, if you don't have a lot of threads you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21293141/2504101)